# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente error al ejecutar un script:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

Tengo una tabla llamada `TBL_ADENDA_ACH` en una base de datos de desarrollo y ejecuto el siguiente script:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_ADENDA_ACH WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE Num_Referencia= 008888002000552
```

Este funciona bien, pero al ejecutarlo en la misma tabla pero en ambiente de producción da el error ya mencionado, ya revisé los tipos de datos,longitud, collation pero sigue el inconveniente.

Comment: ¿Algún lenguaje de programación, herramienta, alguna referencia para poder comprender mejor tu problema?

Comment: Hola Donovan. ¿se trata de SQL Server? Dices que ya revisastes los tipos de datos,longitud, collation, etc... pero sería bueno que incluyeras toda esta información y cualquier otra información pertinente a la pregunta que nos ayudaría a identificar tu problema.

Comment: Que bueno que revisaste los tipos de datos y longitud, pero deberías postearlos acá para poder ayudarte

Comment: Mil disculpas, es SQL Server, en desarrollo el campo es Num_Referencia tipo: varchar, longitud:15, not null, Collatio:SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI    En producción es igual , diferencia es que en producción la longitud es 18, gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Por el mensaje de error, definitivamente e trata de un problema longitud.

Comment: En desarrollo si ejecuto el script así como está no da problema, y en producción si, lo he solucionado agregandole comillas '' , sin embargo no entiendo por qué no me dio ese problema en desarrollo sin comillas, debería de haber dado dicho error en ambos ambientes.

Answer (score 0):

Por el mensaje de error, definitivamente e trata de un problema longitud.

```
Num_Referencia tipo: varchar, longitud:15, not null, Collatio:SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI
```

Puedes solucionar el problema cambiando la longitud del campo a 18.

Comment: Curiosamente hice lo que tu indicas y mi sorpresa fue que no me dio ningún problema en desarrollo.

Comment: perdon, era cambiar la longitud en producción.

Comment: Eso sería una solución, pero dudo mucho que hagan eso en la base de datos de producción debido a políticas internas de la empresa, lo que si puedo hacer es replicar la estructura de la tabla de producción en desarrollo y trabajar con eso.